# ¿Cómo mostrar imágenes desde SqlServer?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy tratando de mostrar mis imagenes desde mi base de datos y me muestra así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero NO me muestra ningún error NI en la consola del navegador.

Tengo mi clase ClsImagen:

```
public class ClsImagen
{
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    [Display(Name = "Subir Archivo")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Por favor, suba un archivo.")]
    public string file { get; set; }
}
```

En mi controlador tengo lo siguiente:

```
    public ActionResult MostrarImagen()
    {
        return View(listarImagenes());
    }

    List<ClsImagen> listarImagenes()
    {
        List<ClsImagen> temporal = new List<ClsImagen>();

        SqlConnection bdConn = new SqlConnection("Server=LAPTOP-SFTPM9NF; Database=Negocios2018; Integrated Security=true");
        using (var bdCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TBL_IMAGENES", bdConn))
        {
            try
            {
                bdCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                bdConn.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = bdCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ClsImagen img = new ClsImagen();
                    img.file = reader["imagen"].ToString();

                    temporal.Add(img);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                bdConn.Close();

                bdCmd.Dispose();
                bdConn.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return temporal;
    }
```

Y en mi vista lo siguiente:

```
@using System.Text;
@model IEnumerable<wsImagen.Models.ClsImagen>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MostrarImagen";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>MostrarImagen</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.file)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>

            @{
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(item.file);
                var bytes64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                var imgsrc = String.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", bytes64);
            }

            <img src="@imgsrc"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

> Lo que trato de hacer en mi vista es convertir de string a un arreglo de bytes y del arreglo de bytes a un stringBase64. Al final le coloco un formato de imagen y al ejecutar NO me muestra la imagen.

No sé que puede estar causando este problema.

Comment: El código para mostrar imagen a priori lo veo bien. Revisa que lo que tengas almacenado está correcto, que se corresponde al mismo nombre de columna "imagen", etc. Si quieres probar el codigo con el string que tengas almacenado puedes hacerlo [aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N9rhbu)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar este ejemplo:

***View:***

```
<img src='@Url.Action("GetImage", "DemoController", new { id = item.FileAttachment.Id })' >
```

***Controller:***

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(int id)
{
    var dataContext = db.FileAttachments.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
    if (dataContext != null)
    {
        return File(dataContext.FileData, dataContext.FileMimeType, dataContext.FileName);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Espero que esto ayude...